# Is it correct: $d^2y = dxdy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I have an ordinary differential equation in which I substitute $\xi = \xi(x), \eta = \eta(x,y)$ and I wish to express $y''_{xx}$ in terms of $\eta''_{\xi\xi}$.

So I get an equation $$d^2\eta=\frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial x^2}dx^2+2\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x\partial y}dxdy+\frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial y^2}dy^2=\frac{d\eta^3}{d\xi^2}(\xi')^2dx^2$$

If it is correct that $dxdy=d(ydx)=d^2y$, then I could divide by $dx^2$ and get the expression. Although it seems to be far from correct and I'm asking for your advice.

Comment: What does $y''_{xx}$ mean? :) I suggest to write you ODE down for better details. :)

Comment: I don't understand where that $\eta^3$ comes from. Also, you can drop the dependence of $\eta$ from $y$, since it is not involved in the change of coordinates.

Comment: I think that the result is $$\frac{\partial^2\eta}{\partial x^2} = \xi'' \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \xi} + (\xi')^2\frac{\partial^2 \eta}{\partial \xi^2}$$.